# PHP SimpleXML to JSON Encode single element array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, simplexml, curly-brackets

I am trying to parse xml with php into a single element json array.

This is what I have:

```
$t = array();

$a=array("url"=>$test->channel->item->link);
array_push($t,$a);
echo json_encode($t);;
```

Which gives me this:

```
[{"url":{"0":"http:www.example.com"}}]
```

But **I am looking for this:**

```
[{"url":"http:www.example.com"}]
```

It seems that `$test->channel->item->link` parses with curly brackets as `{url}`

but if I do `echo $test->channel->item->link`, I get: `www.example.com` without the curly brackets.

Comment: Why are you doing `$a = array()` and not just `$t[] = array()`?

Comment: This is a stripped version of what I am using. the $a = array() doesn't even exists. It's for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it works :)

```
$xmlstr = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' standalone=\'yes\'?>
      <container>
        <channel>
          <item>
            <link>www.example.com</link>
          </item>
        </channel>
      </container>';

$test = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$t = array();
$a = array("url"=>$test->channel->item->link->__toString());
array_push($t,$a);
echo json_encode($t); // [{"url":"www.example.com"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using toString the wrong way. I think I should stop mixing js with php :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this implementation, this is working for me.

```
class eg{
    public $link;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->link = "www.myweb.com";
    }
}

class eg1{
    public $item;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->item = new eg();
    }
}

class eg2{
    public $channel;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->channel = new eg1();
    }
}

$test = new eg2();

$t = array();

$a=array("url"=>$test->channel->item->link);
array_push($t,$a);
echo json_encode($t);
```

And this will render the following string

```
[{"url":"www.myweb.com"}]
```